# Reversing numbers in lines, have a regex already and need to modify it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a regex from a previous thread. This regex seems to only work in some numbers and I'm a total noob to regex and coding. Is there anyway to make all numbers in the text I have reversed? The max total of digits in my text is probably 10 digits in some lines, and in other maybe just 2, sometimes 3 or 4, but max is 10, I'll give examples.

```
goku144

r3apt0r

66958496

Veg3ta123
```

The regex I have only makes some of the numbers reversed, not all, is there anyway to fix the regex provided by horucrux.

> Regex below and link
>
> How to make numbers backwards in notepad++
>
> Step 1. Add a marker for the not-yet-inverted digits.
>
> Find:
>
> \b(\w+?)(\d+)\b
>
> Replace:
>
> $1§$2 You can choose other marker instead of §.
>
> Step 2. Do Replace all enough times with these settings:
>
> Find:
>
> \b(\w+)§(\d*)(\d)\b
>
> Replace:
>
> $1$3§$2
>
> Step 3. Delete all markers.
>
> Find:
>
> \b(\w+\d)§
>
> Replace:
>
> $1

Comment: At the very least you should link to the earlier question, which you have not done.  Also, you should format your by indenting by four or more spaces.

Comment: Added the link sorry

Comment: Please, indent your code and give some test cases with expected result

Comment: Edited post with more details

Comment: What is the expected result for each case?

Comment: Please note that posters here are not just male in gender. Some of our female helpers have expressed the opinion that every time they see references to a "gentlemen" audience, they feel excluded. Therefore, please try to avoid using this sort of address, or indeed any gendered language. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same method as for the other question:

**Step 1**. Add a marker for the not-yet-inverted digits.

Find:

```
\d
```

Replace:

```
§$0
```

**Step 2**. Do <kbd>Replace all</kbd> enough times for inverting digits and, in the same time, removing markers:

Find:

```
§(\d)([^\n]*)§(\d)
```

Replace:

```
$3$2$1
```

**Step 3**. Delete remaining markers (the ones for central digits).

Find:

```
§(\d)
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you deal with notepad++, it is very important to determine maximum length of the sequence as we have no power of programming languages.

Also it would be great to know if you want to reverse any sequence of digits -- in substrings starting with digits, digits in the middle, digits in the end.

Say you want to reverse ALL sequences of digits in your file and the longest sequence has 5 digits. Then:

find: `(?<=\D)(\d)(\d)(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(?=\D)`
replace: `$5$4$3$2$1`